# All textures turn white when switched to renderer shading from material preview shading

Tags: rendering

This is the first Blender project that I'm making and I'm trying to make a Minecraft animation and when it is in material view it looks amazing but when it is in rendered view all the textures turn white.

The background is fine and works in both view.

I am using MCPrep by the way.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Object nodes:
[image]

World nodes:[image]

Material preview:[image]

Renderer view:[image]

EDIT: I think I  found the problem. I was trying to use Cycles with Viewport which doesn't work and when I tried it it works! Are there any other changes I should make?

Comment: Please embed your images directly into your question rather than making us click on links to go and look at them. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post